# Pipe chain with devices

Tags: pipe, block-device

As far as I know, you can have the ability to make pipes between applications, such as this one:

```
$ step1 < input_file | step2 | step3 > result_file
```

And you can access devices such as `/dev/urandom`, `/dev/zero`. `/dev/null`, etc:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom > "output_file"
$ someprog > /dev/null
```

My question is, is it possible to make a pipe with a block device both input and output at the same time? For example, I want to read a `input_file`, send to `/dev/example` (which is `rw`), and then read its output into `output_file`. Can be achieved on a single command just like this:

```
$ cat input_file | /dev/example > output_file
```

or

```
$ /dev/example < input_file > output_file
```

or is it advised to do in two commands?

PS: Maybe I'm misspelling the commands or making syntax errors, please let me know how to get it. I use `sh` or `bash`, I don't know how to use other consoles. If I'm not clear, let me know as English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote makes no sense: `/dev/example` is a file, not a program or a pipe. If you write data to a device, it doesn't go through the device and out to another program.

For example, data written to `/dev/audio` is played on loudspeakers. If you read data from `/dev/audio`, you get data recorded on the microphone. There's no relationship between what is played on the loudspeakers and what is recorded with the microphone.

Comment: Suppose the device (e.g. a dedicated crypto device connected via USB to the PC) processes data like a program and I can access the device from the `/dev` folder. As I can redirect `stdin` and `stdout` at the same time with applications (`app < input > output`), can be done the same with the crypto device (or any device)?

BTW: thanks about the info of `/dev/audio`, I really didn't knew that.

Comment: Usually such a device is there so that `ioctl()` calls can be made to control it, it's not necessarily how to get data in or out. I have seen hardware crypto use a separate process and a *socket* for data transfer.

Comment: @SonicARG It wouldn't work like this. There's no type of device file that acts like a pipe. There isn't a single way to implement this, but I've seen it done in two different ways under Linux: as a character device where data is exchanged through ioctl (so you can't do anything directly from the shell, you need a helper program), or with Linux's kernel sockets (sockets that communicate with a part of the kernel rather than over a network) (so, again, you need a helper program, but there only to open, after than you can get something pipe-like).

Comment: Thanks for the data Gilles, will become more useful in the future. Question solved; closing and accepting your answer.